# how to show binary image data in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

[image]i can show the image using image.open, but how do i display from the binary data?

trying to use plot gets: ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (64,) and (64, 64, 3). this makes sense as that is what the result is supposed to be, but how do i display it?

```
import pathlib
import glob
from os.path import join
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
def parse(image): # my like ings, but with .png instead of .jpeg.
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(image)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [64, 64])
    return image
root = "in/flower_photos/tulips"
path = join(root,"*.jpg")
files = sorted(glob.glob(path))
file=files[0]
image = Image.open(file)
image.show()
binary=parse(file)
print(type(binary))
# how do i see this?
#plt.plot(binary) # does not seem to work
#plt.show() # does not seem to work
```

Answer (score 1):

found a nice [pillow tutorial](http://found%20a%20nice%20pillow%20[tutorial][1].%20%20%20%20%20%20from%20matplotlib%20import%20image%20%20%20%20%20from%20matplotlib%20import%20pyplot%20%20%20%20%20from%20PIL%20import%20Image%20%20%20%20%20#%20load%20the%20image%20%20%20%20%20filename='Sydney-Opera-House.jpg'%20%20%20%20%20im%20=%20Image.open(filename)%20%20%20%20%20#%20summarize%20some%20details%20about%20the%20image%20%20%20%20%20print(im.format)%20%20%20%20%20print(im.mode)%20%20%20%20%20print(im.size)%20%20%20%20%20#%20show%20the%20image%20%20%20%20%20#image.show()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20load%20image%20as%20pixel%20array%20%20%20%20%20data%20=%20image.imread(filename)%20%20%20%20%20#%20summarize%20shape%20of%20the%20pixel%20array%20%20%20%20%20print(data.dtype)%20%20%20%20%20print(data.shape)%20%20%20%20%20#%20display%20the%20array%20of%20pixels%20as%20an%20image%20%20%20%20%20pyplot.imshow(data)%20%20%20%20%20pyplot.show()%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-and-manipulate-images-for-deep-learning-in-python-with-pil-pillow/).

```
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot
from PIL import Image
# load the image
filename='Sydney-Opera-House.jpg'
im = Image.open(filename)
# summarize some details about the image
print(im.format)
print(im.mode)
print(im.size)
# show the image
#image.show()

# load image as pixel array
data = image.imread(filename)
# summarize shape of the pixel array
print(data.dtype)
print(data.shape)
# display the array of pixels as an image
pyplot.imshow(data)
pyplot.show()
```